# Visual Studio Installer not creating .msi file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

I have developed an application on visual studio 2010. I am trying to create setup for it by using Visual Studio's built in Setup Wizard [shown in snapshot below].

[image]

I added basic details in its properties window... when i click on Build this output comes.

[image]

& there is no .msi file in Setup folder. There are only 2 files in its folder. One is setup application & another is windows installer file. but when i run them this is what comes up

[image]

is there any relation between the Warning that i have highlighted in OUTPUT snapshot. Or is there anything that i a not doing right? .. I have check Public key attribute in Product.xml & have updated it to with this [MSDN thread advises](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a2220512-0cb1-4c07-b750-ae1d7673e187/the-value-of-the-publickey-attribute-in-windows-installer-31-does-not-match-that-of-?forum=winformssetup).

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/the-windows-installer-service-could-not-be/6fc53a09-8acb-463b-bd2b-aa728c841e7b

Comment: i suppose no one knows answer??

Comment: Show file extensions in Windows Explorer.  The "Windows Installer" file is an .MSI file.  I don't suggest installing your own MSIs on your dev machine. Especially if you are brand new to MSI.  This is what snapshotted VMs are for.

Comment: There's no connection. That public key error is probably the bootstrapper building the setup.exe. Each redist has a hash and public key in the base Xml file for the bootstrap manifest. It looks like there is an update or change and they no longer match. The "Windows Installer service could not be accessed" is an unfortunately common Windows error that could affect all MSI files, so maybe all MSI files are affected not just use yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved... There was no problem a all.. the .msi file is in the folder with the name Setup2. ues it was the .msi setup file.. the problem was with my windows. it was corrupted. I installed that setup on other computers & its working....